# Prevent exposure of sensitive data against PCI standards - response.getWriter().write(xml.toString())

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I am fixing code against the code audit report. It says "PREVENT EXPOSURE OF SENSITIVE DATA" against the line having the syntax `response.getWriter().write(xml.toString())`. The whole code is below.

```
String alertId =  request.getParameter("alertId") != null ? request.getParameter("alertId") : "";
                    String desc=AAAA.getBBBB(Long.parseLong(AAAA.getCCCC(alertId)));
                    StringBuffer xml = new StringBuffer();

                    xml.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
                    xml.append("<parent>");
                    xml.append("<child>");
                    xml.append("<alertDesc>");
                    xml.append(desc);
                    xml.append("</alertDesc>");
                    xml.append("</child>");
                    xml.append("</parent>");

                    response.getWriter().write(xml.toString());  // ISSUE IN THIS LINE
                    response.setContentType("text/xml");
                    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

I have done sufficient home work and can fix it for the XSS attack and used ESAPI for the same. But dont know how to fix this one. Please give suggestions
The report has the below message against the reported issue.
"Leakage of toString() result ("xml") via web page"

after the day long r&d i found that the sax parser can help me in this case. it is actually  a memory leakage at the StringBuffer.toString() syntax, due to which sensitive data is getting exposed and lost. but i dont know how to implement that. also at some place i found the use of StringBuilder() class instead of StringBuffer() class. Can anybody help me or give their valuable suggestions. 
Thanks in advance.

Also I have the same issue for another type of the code. it is below.

```
StringBuffer content = (StringBuffer)file.get("content");
response.setContentLength((int)content.length());
            response.getWriter().write(content.toString());
```

Again i dont know how to fix this one. THE issue is same leakage of sensitive data been reported by the tool.

Comment: I think that problem is not StringBuffer but with the information you are exposuring. Is there any sensitive information in "desc" as a credit card number or a CVV code?

Comment: no desc does not have any sensitive data. it is been reported by the audit tool only and i need to give the fix for the issue only.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the auditor what they meant?

Comment: dear, i am working on a client project. the client has done the code audit and given us the report with the issue and messages for different audit standards and i need to fix them thats all i can say. if u know the solution then please tell. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content.toString() needs to be properly validated. use ESAPI to validate it strictly. writing directly to response is really vulnerable and if if the data is output from a method having request as input then its twice vulnerable. major security issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I have told in my comment, I do not thing that the comment has something to do with the code itself but with the exposure of sensitive data. I have read the PCI-DSS document and I don't remember it says anything about how something it should be coded (regardless good practices). You can take a look to all [PCI documentation](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php) available by yourself. It is a hard task, a better approach would be to try to find out what the consultant meant.

It is really difficult to fix something when you don't know where the problem is.