# Leakage of toString() result for a PrintWriter

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Presvent exposure of sensitive data against PCI standards - response.getWriter().write(xml.toString())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076992/presvent-exposure-of-sensitive-data-against-pci-standards-response-getwriter)

I am getting the message "Leakage of toString() result" in the following Java code:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<a href=\""
            + XYZAC
            + "?"
            + fieldArray.get(i)
            + "="
            + content[j].split("=")[0]
            + "&sessionId="
            + request.getAttribute("sessionId").toString()
            + "&mSA=" + pHNO
            + "\"" + ">"
            + content[j].split("=")[1]
            + "</a>");
```

Can any one tell me where the leakage is, and how to fix it? The message is from a code auditing tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to toString is redundant. Perhaps that is what it is complaining about.

I would remove it and try again.